# Save a list of unique Strings in the ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I read data from a text file, so there may be:

```
John
Mary
John
Leeds
```

I now need to get 3 unique elements in the ArrayList, because there are only 3 unique values in the file output (as above).

I can use a HashTable and add information to it, then simply copy its data into the List.
Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Why do you need to store it in a `List`?  Do you actually require the data to be ordered or support index-based look-ups?

I would suggest storing the data in a `Set`.  If ordering is unimportant you should use `HashSet`.  However, if you wish to preserve ordering you could use `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: Why? Cause Lists are used most often and it are easy to work with. I think if you write code for other developers it's better to return a List type than any other type.

Comment: Not necessarily.  The only case where you'd need a list is if you want random indexed access to items in the collections.  Otherwise it would be preferrable to go with plain HashSet or LinkedHashSet.

Comment: In my opinion the code is cleaner when you use indice. You have the control over "where you are" inside the data structure. It may come from my experience with C language.

Comment: @EugeneP: Don't write C code in Java. In every language, it is better to take advantage of its own features.

Comment: @EugeneP: I disagree that it's better to return a List than any other type.  It's better to return the appropriate data structure.  If uniqueness is important but ordering isn't then return a Set.  If neither are important then return a Collection.  If you only wish to iterate over the elements then return an Iterable.  The more decoupled the calling code is from the internal implementation the easier it is to make changes or substitute in a different implementation.

Comment: @Mak Agree with you. Yet no one will remove for(;;) loop from Java. Remember where Java comes from? If you have a number of ways how to iterate over a structure, it's up to you to pick one of those.

Comment: @EugeneP: I guess your point is that there is no reason to use something just to conform with dogma. I don't disagree. But in this case, a `List` is both unnecessary and less efficient (O(n^2) vs O(n)). Unless you actually need to preserve the order of the `String`s, using a `List` is really a worse choice in practice. That is not the case for `for(;;)`. It may be that using a `List` comes more naturally to you because C does not really have any `Set` like data structure, but it is really not the natural thing to use.

Comment: The point about List and Set is that a Set will have unique values (advantage over List) and better iterator performance. However, a Set is not ordered. So if it is truly a list of non-unique things and ordering matters, List is the right answer. If it is a set of unique things, Set is the right answer (and implement a Comparator if needed when iterating).

Comment: This answer could use a code sample. I wrote a simple test with `HashSet<String>` and it would allow duplicate values so perhaps it isn't a builtin feature.

Answer (score 69):

If you have a `List` containing duplicates, and you want a `List` without, you could do:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(oldList));
```

That is, wrap the old list into a set to remove duplicates and wrap that set in a list again.

Comment: I guess, there is no guarantee that the sorting of the `newList` will be the same as the one of `oldList`, or?

Comment: O.k. I found the answer to my comment: If you use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`, you preserve the order.

Answer (score 18):

You can check [list.contains()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) before adding.

```
if(!list.contains(value)) {
    list.add(value);
}
```

I guessed it would be obvious!  However, adding items to a HashSet and then creating a list from this set would be more efficient.

Comment: I suppose it uses the "equals" method?

Comment: Yes it does use equals() on the the string internally.

Comment: Yep. Thanks. In my case that would be preferable, 'cause the code will be kept clean. But I guess the HashTable algorithm is faster than contains method, unless they use a HashTable internally.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `set` instead of a list. Take a look at here: [Java Collections Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) and specifically about Sets here: [Java Sets Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

In a nutshell, sets contain one of something. Perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it:

```
import groovy.io.*;
def arr = ["5", "5", "7", "6", "7", "8", "0"]
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>( arr.asList() ));
System.out.println( uniqueList )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use Java 8 stream's distinct

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

// public static void main(String args[]) ...

// list of strings, including some nulls and blanks as well ;)
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("John", "Mary", "John", "Leeds", 
null, "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "C", "", null);
 
// collect distinct without duplicates
List<String> distinctElements = list.stream()
                        .distinct()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
 
// unique elements
System.out.println(distinctElements);
```

Output:

```
 [John, Mary, Leeds, null, , A, B, C, D]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<String> distinctElements = list.stream()
            .distinct().filter(s -> s != null && s != "")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will collect the distinct items and also avoid null or empty String

Answer (score -1):

```
class HashSetList<T extends Object>
    extends ArrayList<T> {

    private HashSet<Integer> _this = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(T obj) {
        if (_this.add(obj.hashCode())) {
            super.add(obj);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I now use those kind of structure for little programs, I mean you have little overhead in order to have getters and setters but uniqueness. Moreover you can override `hashCode` to decide wether your item equals another one.

Comment: Nice idea, but... what about remove and add(int, *) etc? This solution is not complete.